# How can I call <figcaption> with jquery and insert into <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to call the content held within the  element and insert it into the  tag so that it can be used as the caption on the lightbox.

The html looks like:

```
<figure class="image">
    <img alt="sadasdasd" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02580/japan-train_2580841k.jpg" />
    <figcaption>adsasdsa</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The jQuery I am using is below:

```
$('#article-copy img').each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
    caption = $("figcaption"),
    href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + href + '" class="fresco" data-fresco-group="unique_name" data-fresco-caption="' + caption + '"></a>');
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: where is the caption located?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call"?

Comment: Sorry I didnt add the correct html     <figure class="image"><img alt="sadasdasd" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02580/japan-train_2580841k.jpg" />
<figcaption>adsasdsa</figcaption>
</figure>
The caption is located inside the <figcaption> tags, I need to get whatever is inside there and insert that into the <a> tag so that it will show in the lightbox correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are saying you are getting the img element when it is clicked, and so you are getting the href to use. However you are not able to reach the figcaption because it is not on the img element. It is the sibling element. We can get that using [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$img.next('figcaption').text();
```

but there are other functions like [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) you might prefer to use. You can see your options in the jQuery [tree traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) api docs. Using next() you get this:

```
$('#article-copy img').each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
    caption = $img.next('figcaption').text(),
    href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + href + '" class="fresco" data-fresco-group="unique_name" data-fresco-caption="' + caption + '"></a>');
});
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped, could you accept this as the answer?